# How to access a static member field in a static method in cpp

Tags: c++

I have the following .h file.

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <thread>

namespace MyNamespace
{

class Util
{
public:
    static void SetMainThreadId(std::thread::id threadId);

private:
    static std::thread::id m_mainThreadId;
};

}
```

And I have the following .cpp file

```
#include "Util.h"

namespace MyNamespace
{

class Util
{
    static void Util::SetMainThreadId(std::thread::id threadId)
    {
        Util::m_mainThreadId = threadId;
    }
};

}
```

How come the code above simply doesn't compile? I am trying to assign a static variable inside a static method. What is wrong with this code?

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't compile because the modifiers only appear in headers. `static` should not be in the implementation of the function.

This should work:

```
void Util::SetMainThreadId(std::thread::id threadId)        
{
    m_mainThreadId = threadId;
}
```

Also note there is no `class Util` in the cpp. That is also a definition which is already done in the header file. The implementation uses the class name directly in the function declaration: `class::func (params)`

I recommend you read-up on C++ syntax before attempting any coding. Let alone one that involves a complex topic like threads.

Comment: Thank you both complete cpp noob here. Getting rid of the `Class Util {` in cpp file done the trick.

Comment: It's fine, we all gotta start somewhere. But take it one step at a time. When learning a new language, the best course of action is to first know what the language can do (don't expect to write an operating system in *Lua* or *Squirrel* - yes, there is a language called Squirrel and its script files are called *nuts*). Next learn its paradigms (for example *type-safe*, *OOP* etc), then its syntax. Then start practicing (but usually the first lessons should be displaying text on terminals, reading or writing text files, **NOT** multithreading, network traffic management, making games etc).

Comment: `Util::m_mainThreadId` can be simply `m_mainThreadId`; the function is a member of `Util`, so the names in `Util` don't need the class qualifier.

Comment: @PeteBecker THank you. This exact comment came up in my code review lmao